# Blender Character modelling - Issue with insert "I"

Tags: modeling

I am having issue with a character modelling tutorial... This tutorial time stamp: 22:25 Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWh113galYo&list=PL442b4igUDI87pKEVQDNUewNbga5Mcv4w&index=1&t=1346s

After pressing "I" the area is divided into two parts in my project instead of 1. Image from tutorial.[image: Tutorial image]
I can provide more information if needed.

I have tried to disable the mirror modifier and subsurface modifier but the same happens and I have no idea why. I checked that there are no extra lines in the mesh or anything that would seem to cause the issue and I am so confused how to try fix this.

What happens when I try to follow tutorial: [image]

Comment: Press I to *Inset*, then B to turn off the *Boundary* option. It's displayed on the top of the window. You use a *Mirror* modifier and only the base mesh, one half of your mesh, is editable. In the center the base mesh is open, that's the boundary and it affects the inset operation.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Thanks for the reply, I will update if I managed to fix it.

Comment: Ah it was so simple lol, it is fine now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen the tutorial, but as someone commented, I suspect you either need to disable the boundary option for the inset operation, or apply the mirror modifier. Modifiers work on top of all regular edits, so you are performing an inset operation on a half model, and then it’s getting mirrored. The boundary option will make the inset operation go right up to the edge of the half model, or you can apply the modifier and be working with all real mesh.

Comment: Someone Blunder commented :)

Comment: Thanks I will try check this tomorrow!